# How to debug this recursion function python

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

I am working on this question from school, and I wrote the function I thought was the right one (we need to use recursion with no loops)

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target):
    '''
    numbers - a list of positive integers
    target - a non-negative integer
    returns True if the list 'numbers' has a sub-list with sum 'target',
            False otherwise.
    '''
    # Your code for question #4 starts here
    if sum(numbers[1:]) == target or target == 0:
        return True
    if sum(numbers[1:]) == (target - numbers[0]):
        return True
    if len(numbers) == 1 and numbers[0] == target:
        return True
    if len(numbers) == 1 and numbers[0] != target:
        return False
    else:
        subset_sum(numbers[1:], target)
```

For some inputs get the right output like `subset_sum([4,4,4], 12)` or `subset_sum([4,4,4], 8)` but for `subset_sum([4,4,4], 4)` I get no output.

Can someone take a look and tell me what's wrong here?
When it doesn't give any output there are no errors, just blank.

Comment: I'm not sure that the solution you present, even with the correction from soon fulfils the requirements you have been given.

Comment: @quamrana it didnt... but i dont understand why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the result of `subset_sum` in the `else` branch:

```
else:
    return subset_sum(numbers[1:], target)
```

Comment: This can be simplified by removing the `else:`, leaving just the return.

Comment: Done! but now i get wrong output for : 'subset_sum([1,2,3,4],  6)'.  any idea why?

Comment: @Beginner, well yes, but in order for you to learn you should go back to your teacher or work it out for yourself. (Hint: perhaps you could manually find all the sub-lists of a given list yourself and try to work out how a recursive program could find them)